# How to display user inputted blogs in flask production server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn and nginx to serve a flask application, my website has a blogging feature where users can write blogs, once they do, their input is saved as an html file (I use tinyMCE to generate it) and a flask view is added to a views.py file. Now, in deployment, I just used

```
use_reloader=True
```

This ensured that every time a new file was added, it was detected, now in production, I don't know how to implement it, gunicorn has `--reload` option but the docs say that it's only for development. Can someone please provide an insight on how to implement this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new view for every html file. You could use a generic view that renders the appropriate html according to the url requested.

Comment: yes, but the server doesn't detect a new html file being added, I keep getting 404 error